# Attempts to publish RabbitMQ data seem to be blocked

Tags: networking, firewall, ports

I am using [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) for syncing data between two applications. These applications reside in 2 different countries—the U.S. and China—and RabbitMQ is being accessed from both the locations.

Sometimes data is not being published to RabbitMQ server form any of the applications.

The error I am getting is this:

```
Missed server heartbeat {"exception":"[object] (PhpAmqpLib\\Exception\\AMQPHeartbeatMissedExce ption(code: 0): Missed server heartbeat at vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connect ion/AbstractConnection.php:609)
```

Comment: What countries are these applications in? Also, are you 100% sure that all [required ports](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports) are accessible?

Comment: One application is in china and the other one is in US

Comment: Considering China’s “[Great Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall)” it would be a solid that data is being blocked deliberately by China’s tech infrastructure.